# Fill Dropdownlist using values in ListItem is giving error

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, listitem

I want to fill the `dropdownlist` whose data is coming in a list object. So I tried like below

```
private void GetR4GStates(List<UMSLocationDetails> LocationDetail)
{   
    for(var i=0; i < LocationDetail.Count; i++)
    {
        ddlMaintenanceZone.Items.Add(new LocationDetail[i], i.ToString());
    }
}
```

But I am getting error as:

> No overload for method `Add` takes 2 arguments.

How should I fill my list with Text and Values?

I get error at line
`ddlMaintenanceZone.Items.Add(new LocationDetail[i], i.ToString());`

Below is the screenshot of the error

[image]

**update**

HTML of dropdown

```
<select id="ddlMaintenanceZone" runat="server">
    <option value="Select">Select Maint Zone</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Add` method does not take two parameters. **But** you can pass in a [single parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s6873c(v=vs.110).aspx) which has the `Text` and `Value` *properties* set on it. That is the `ListItem`. The code looks like:

```
ddlMaintenanceZone.Items.Add(
    new ListItem("whateveryouwantthetexttobe", "whateveryouwantthevaluetobe"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Why
`ddlMaintenanceZone.Items.Add(new LocationDetail[i], i.ToString());`
instead of
`ddlMaintenanceZone.Items.Add(new LocationDetail[i]);` ?

List LocationDetail is waiting for one arg not two.

You can use array if you want.